# How to convert tuples in nested list to lists?

Tags: python

I need to find three values in a list that returns the value of zero. The problem that I have with my code is that it returns a nested list with tuples instead of lists.

Input:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]
```

Output:

```
[(-1, -1, 2), (-1, 0, 1)]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]
```

My code:

```
def threeSum(a):
    N = len(a)
    c=[]
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i+1, N):
            for k in range(j+1, N):
                if a[i]+a[j]+a[k] == 0:
                    c.append([a[i],a[j],a[k]])
    b_set = set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in c)
    #remove duplicates
    return list(b_set)

print(threeSum([-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]))
```

Comment: Why not just `[list(sub) for sub in result]`?

Comment: @mypetlion that `tuple` constructor is there for a reason, though.

Comment: This would return {(-1, -1, 2), (-1, 0, 1)}.

Comment: `map(list, list_of_tuples)`

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this?  Perhaps there's a better answer if we understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this line

```
b_set = [list(x) for x in b_set]
```

before your return statement for your expected output
Change your return statement to just

```
return b_set
```